# Insert into ... values ( FROM SELECT ... FROM ... )

Tags: mysql

```sql
insert into tab3(a,b,c,d,e)
values ( 1, 
         ( select  a  
           from tab2 
           left join tab1 ON tab1.a = tab2.a 
           where tab2.b="x" ),
         'somting1',
         'somting2',
         'somting3');
```

the probelm is if the select return more then 1 row this function not working and i get error  "the result is more then 1 row"

i want if have more then 1 row in result of the select to insert all the row whit the select rutrun but also whit the cost varibel same my code

Comment: `left join` will have null for non matching results and you may expect to get more than one row. Provide some more info ex: table structures with data and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Besides from the fact that your join seems to have no use you can do

```
insert into tab3 (a,b,c,d,e) 
select 1, tab2.a, 'somting1', 'somting2', 'somting3'
from tab2 
left join tab1 ON tab1.a = tab2.a 
where tab2.b = 'x'
```